# Is there a difference between lobbying in a supranational government like the EU as opposed to a national government like the U.S.?

Tags: european-union, lobbying

Is there a difference between lobbying in a supranational government like the EU as opposed to a national government like the U.S.? I am guessing that lobbying for the EU is a lot less effective than lobbying for the U.S., is this the case or it's actually not that different and the outcome and the process are basically the same? If not, could you explain the differences, especially in terms of effectiveness if we were to lobby for a private company like Microsoft?